# li border to include absolute child

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm building hover dropdown menus in CSS and I want to style each primary `li`'s border to surround its (absolute) child `li` on hover. At the moment, the border only surrounds the primary `li` content. For the sake of the demo, the border is always present, but I'll toggle it on hover or click later.

```
<section class="divider fullwidth">
  <div class="divider-cont">
    <div id="divider-links">
      <span id="filter-by">Filter Events By</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Genre <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Genre 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Genre 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Genre 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Venue & Location <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Time of Day <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Price Range <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

section.divider .divider-cont {
  padding: 0 2%;
}
section.divider .divider-cont #filter-by {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
section.divider .divider-cont ul {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
section.divider .divider-cont ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15px;
}
section.divider .divider-cont ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
section.divider .divider-cont ul li a {
  text-align: center;
}
section.divider .divider-cont ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 0;
}
section.divider .divider-cont ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
section.divider .divider-cont ul li a {
  padding-right: 50px;
}
section.divider .divider-cont ul li a, section.divider .divider-cont ul li a:hover, section.divider .divider-cont ul li a:active, section.divider .divider-cont ul li a:visited {
  color: grey;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/apmMqL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may draw the `border` from the `ul` showing up :

```
&:hover ul { 
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 -1px;
  border:solid 1px gray;
  border-top:none;
  left:0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpjGxa?editors=1100

Comment: This works great until I add a box-shadow. Sorry, I would've mentioned it earlier if I'd realised it'd influence the answer.

Comment: @MarioParra can you show what you mean about the box-shadow ?

Comment: Sure: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/vgXwzJ?editors=1100. Ideally, I want the box-shadow to surround the entire `li`, but it only surrounds the secondary part since they're joined together.

Comment: @MarioParra ah okay., you can use multiple shadow and draw them on both li and ul http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JERqqb

Comment: Thanks! That did it.